# Deduce PDF of a mixed distribution from the CDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

CDF given as:

$$  F(x)= 
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{4}&\text{ if }& 0\leq x<\dfrac{1}{4}\\
\dfrac{1}{2}&\text{ if }&\dfrac{1}{4}\leq x<\dfrac{1}{2}\\
\dfrac{3}{4}&\text{ if }&\dfrac{1}{2}\leq x<\dfrac{3}{4}\\
\dfrac{x+3}{5}&\text{ if }&\dfrac{3}{4}\leq x<2\\
1  &\text{ if }& x\geq2.
\end{cases}$$

Then I tried to calculate PDF as given below: 
$$  f(x)= 
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{4}&\text{ if }& 0\leq x<\dfrac{1}{4}\\
\dfrac{1}{4}&\text{ if }&\dfrac{1}{4}\leq x<\dfrac{1}{2}\\
\dfrac{1}{4}&\text{ if }&\dfrac{1}{2}\leq x<\dfrac{3}{4}\\
\dfrac{1}{5}&\text{ if }&\dfrac{3}{4}\leq x<2\\
\end{cases}$$

I am having problem in last segment of PDF. Please someone tell me. Will it be zero? And how am I suppose to find cdf as $1$ out of it?

Comment: Something is wrong in the second line ...

Comment: @Isham Yes thank you edited that out.

Comment: From the given CDF, you see the function are piecewisely constants for $x < 3/4$, with jumps of magnitude $1/4$ on $0, 1/4, 1/2$ respectively, therefore it just has 3 discrete point mass and no such pdf exist on that interval. On $(3/4, 2)$, the CDF is a linear function so it is just a continuous uniform distribution over that region. Note there are no more jumps on $3/4$ or $2$.

Comment: what will be value at $x \geq 2$?

Comment: I edited the post. Please consider the changes.

Comment: @zoli Thank you. But i still didnt get any answer. Any thoughts?

Comment: OK. I will give an answer.

Comment: Sorry but when $x<\frac14$, how do you deduce $f(x)=\frac14$ from $F(x)=\frac14$? Please be specific.

Comment: @Did its a discrete case its actually at $x=0$ isnt it?

Comment: Sorry but your comment cannot be parsed.

Comment: I am very beginner at these things so please correct me at every step. I can do mistakes that's why i asked this question it in first place. I don't understand what are you saying.

Comment: Community down voting questions is totally feel like bullying here. Of course beginner can't see everything like experts do.

Comment: Hard to answer this latter comment. The Community is expecting more care, For example, it turned out that you did not understand how to calculate the pdf. Yet, your question was not like "I was told the the pdf is the derivative of the cdf. But here, there is not derivative. Pls. help me understand what is going on with this pdf?" (With all due respect...)

Comment: The word PDF matters ok . But that was an mistake. Even i showed the pmf for discrete and pdf for continuous case myself in the question i solved it myself. I had problem in the last segment i said that is what will be the pdf or pmf for $x\geq 2$.

Comment: "I don't understand what are you saying" Let me repeat then: How do you deduce that $f(x)=\frac14$ when $0<x<\frac14$ from the fact that $F(x)=\frac14$ when $0<x<\frac14$? This is asking about your thought process hence you should be able to answer it, beginner or not.

Comment: Jump at zero is $\dfrac{1}{4}$.

Answer (score 1):

There is no pdf. The distribution is a mixture of a continuous part and that of a discrete part.

The discrete part is $\frac14,\frac14,\frac14$ at $0$, $\frac14$, $\frac12$, respectively. The continuous part is

$$g(x)=\begin{cases}\frac15&\text{ if }&\frac34<x<2\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

The following figure depicts this distribution:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. You are sensible here i guess.

Comment: Please, take a look again. The current version is better.

Comment: Sorry but the PDF is nowhere equal to $\frac45$. Or are you alluding to a conditional density (which would be a bad idea)? (Also, please note that "the probability that the distribution is continuous" can only be zero in the context, since the distribution is not continuous...)

Comment: @Did Sir you really have to give me an answer for this .http://prntscr.com/i3t6a4 This was the original question. I solved this and got correct answer. But just find me the pmf for discrete case and pdf for continuous case out of this CDF.